.desktop file won't run
I want to run an appimage using a .desktop file, but it's not working. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Also, I want to be able to put it on my panel as an app.
[Desktop Entry]
Name=osu
Exec=/home/aaravy/Downloads/osu.AppImage
Type=Application

OS info:
Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Cinnamon 6.0.4

Have you made it executable? Use chmod +x your_app.desktop
After it's executable, you may be able to add it to the panel.

Thanks! This worked for me.

This can be very awkward to get working sometimes. (It seems to be very fussy.)
Also note this is 24.04 only. It is different as you go back through the OS.
Firstly, they can be run in two ways. One with the first line as [Desktop Entry] and the other as #[Desktop Entry] (commented out) If you run it as the first option you also have to enable the icon with a right menu click Allow Launching. If you choose the second option then you right click and select Run As Program (with this second option you don't need the first option Allow Launching to be selected before disabling it) before the 'comment out action'.) It is doubly confusing as both menu options are only shown in context only.
Example1
[Desktop Entry]
Terminal=false
Type=Application
EntryType=Application
StartupNotify=true
Icon=org.gnome.Rhythmbox
Name[en_GB]=RhythmboxCust.desktop
Exec=bash "/home/xxxxp/Rhymb23.sh"

It will show the icon fully and without an inhibit cross on it and it works with double click.
Example 2
#[Desktop Entry]
Terminal=false
Type=Application
EntryType=Application
StartupNotify=true
Icon=org.gnome.Rhythmbox
Name[en_GB]=RhythmboxCust.desktop
Exec=bash "/home/xxxxp/Rhymb23.sh"

It will show a greyed out icon with a cross but if you right click on it and select Run As Program it will run the same. Double click though will report it is broken whether or not it was left select to Allow Launching or not.
Also note that if I change the Exec line to: -
Exec=/bin/gnome-terminal -e "/home/xxxxxp/Rhymb23.sh"

It will run as the former but not as the latter.
The target (edited a bit) shell script is
#!/bin/bash
DIR1='file:///home/....p/Music'
RHYDB=$HOME/.local/share/rhythmbox/rhythmdb2.xml
PLYF23=$HOME/.local/share/rhythmbox/playlists23.xml
echo "Current settings are: -"
gsettings get org.gnome.rhythmbox.rhythmdb locations
echo "Changing setup to $DIR1"
gsettings set org.gnome.rhythmbox.rhythmdb locations "['$DIR1']"
/bin/rhythmbox --rhythmdb-file=$RHYDB --playlists-file=$PLYF23


If you want to add this to the Gnome menu copy the .desktop file you have created to either of the following depending on whether you want it to be global or just local to the current user: -
.local/share/applications/
/usr/share/applications/

You might need to restart gnome which I do by just logging out and back in again.
Enjoy.
Hope this is of some help.

This helps, but it won't let me put it on the panel. Is there any way to put it on the panel? I'm using a cinnamon desktop environment.

@Aarav I have added a bit to answer adding .desktop files to system menus etc for gnome which is what I use. Might be the same for cinnamon? Worth a try?

thanks so much! I was able to finally pin it to my panel.
