Make an application executable in terminal a Dock shortcut
I am running Ubuntu 24.04. I just installed scid (a chess database) with:
./configure
make
make install

I can run the program from the terminal with ./scid. How can I get a shortcut to this program onto the dock? (The menu where you can put applications on the bottom or side of the screen). I think the executable files are in /usr/local/bin

scid is available in the Ubuntu software repositories so can be installed and managed using sudo apt update && sudo apt install scid

This question is similar to: How to add programs to the Unity Launcher or Ubuntu Dock?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

One way to check if a program is already part of the Ubuntu 24.04 data set is to use 'Synaptic' To install this check you are up-to-date (see above) then  'sudo apt-get install synaptic' run the package then search for 'scid' in this case. Bare in mind it might not be the latest version. Quite often the page name and program don't have the same name though.

How to create a desktop icon and add it to the side bar. See answer @  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1523597/desktop-file-wont-run/1523652#1523652 For adding it to the taskbar read through to the end.
