"Nautilus is needed for Desktop Icons" error in Ubuntu
I've just recently performed a fresh install of Ubuntu Desktop 24.04 LTS, Noble Numbat. I've booted it up a few times, and have installed a few of my usual applications. In previous installations, I've liked to have desktop shortcuts for my favorite programs - I've just installed WPS Office and added a desktop shortcut for that. Usually, when adding a desktop shortcut, I right-click the new shortcut, click "Properties", and enable "Executable as a program" - then I right-click the shortcut again, and click "Allow Launching".
I tried to do this today, with my first shortcut - however, when clicking "Properties" in the context menu, instead of a Properties window for the shortcut I am presented with a notification bubble - saying "Nautilus is needed for Desktop Icons" and requesting I install Nautilus. It says "For this functionality to to work in Desktop Icons, you must install "Nautilus" in your system."
I already have Nautilus, a.k.a. GNOME Files, installed - it came preinstalled, as it has done with every installation of Ubuntu Desktop I've ever used. As you can see in the screenshot below, I have the Nautilus icon pinned to the dash - and I've used it several times to manage my files since installing Ubuntu.

I'd be very grateful if someone could help me resolve this issue.

Full system details:
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble
CPU: Intel Core i7
RAM: 24GB (16GB + 8GB)
GPU: NVIDIA Geforce GTX 965M + Intel HD Integrated Graphics
Static hostname: Ubuntu
Icon name: computer-laptop
Chassis: laptop 
Operating System: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Kernel: Linux 6.8.0-31-generic
Architecture: x86-64
Hardware Vendor: HP
Hardware Model: OMEN by HP Laptop
Firmware Version: F.09
Firmware Date: Tue 2016-07-19
Firmware Age: 8y 2month 2w 3d

Edit:
The result of running ls -al ~/Desktop is:
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  2 administrator administrator 4096 Oct  4 16:27 .
drwxr-x--- 16 administrator administrator 4096 Oct  2 11:20 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 administrator root           445 Oct  4 16:27 wps-office-prometheus.desktop

...And the result of running cat ~/Desktop/wps-office-prometheus.desktop is:
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=Use WPS Writer to office work.
Comment[zh_CN]=使用 WPS 2019进行办公
Exec=/usr/bin/wps %F
GenericName=WPS
GenericName[zh_CN]=WPS 2019
Name=WPS 2019
Name[zh_CN]=WPS 2019
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Office;WordProcessor;Qt;
X-DBUS-ServiceName=
X-DBUS-StartupType=
X-KDE-SubstituteUID=false
X-KDE-Username=
Icon=wps-office2019-kprometheus
InitialPreference=3
StartupWMClass=wpsoffice


Please note, I'm quite new to asking questions on this community. I hope my question is well-written; however if I've done something wrong, instead of downvoting right away, please consider leaving a comment and giving me a chance to edit my question first. Thanks =)

I've not experienced that issue but my first thought is to install Extension Manager and from there install Desktop Icons NG (DING) click on the cogwheel icon and adjust Settings if required to see if that makes a difference. Related Q&A

It works on my rig OS 24.04. Could you append to your question the result of the following commend 'ls -al ~/Desktop' & 'cat ~/Desktop/wps-office-prometheus.desktop'

@david I have added the information you have requested. I hope it helps. I've noted that it appears the shortcut works, as intended - without me actually needing to edit it. I should have tried running it before assuming I'd need to change the shortcut's properties for it to work. N =)

There are two ways to use desktop icons to run executables. Some extra information on this at the following link:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1523597/desktop-file-wont-run/1523652#1523652
