SH script not executing from desktop
Running Ubuntu 24.04,
Created link to SH script and placed shortcut on desktop.
The shell script file is marked as executable.
When I double click on the desktop icon, a text editor is opened.
Any help is appreciated.

Take a look at the answer at  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1523597/desktop-file-wont-run/1523652#1523652
