In Ubuntu 24.04, cannot make an executable an "app"
What, exactly, is an "app"?
This question arises from my buying a new computer, now running Ubuntu 24.04 as does my old machine, on which I am writing this.
On my old machine, I still run an application called SCID.  It is a database of chess games.  It is version 4.7.4.  This has been replaced, apparently by version 5.0.2 which is hosted on SourceForge. This is not available in the App Center but is available on searching from "Show Apps".  Install from there fails, however.
Someone told me on the SCID mailing list that he just builds the program from source.  I tried this and it does work, producing a file that is executable and works.  However, it does not produce an application that can be put in the "Show Apps" grid or be pinned to the dash.  How may I pin this program to the dash?

What you want is called a "Launcher" in Ubuntu. It is a file with the a .desktop file extension. Since you built the app you will have to create a launcher file for it. Search here.

Take a look at the second (?) answer to the following question to help you build your launcher for 24.04 & later.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1523597/desktop-file-wont-run/1523652#1523652 As you have a legacy version of the icon you can start your build from that one.

I also use SCID, and this was a problem for me as well. I am sharing my scid.desktop file, which needs to be placed in ~/.local/share/applications
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Scid vs. PC
Comment=Scid vs. PC ver 4.16.1 (07/2016)
Type=Application
Exec=/workspace/software/scid_linux/scid/scid
Icon=/workspace/software/scid_linux/scid/img/scid.gif
Terminal=false

You can change the comment to match the version of the executable that you have, the Exec has to point to the executable, and you can choose any Icon which can be displayed in the Launcher.
Categories=Game

If the project includes an icon, perhaps it also includes a desktop file as well, and it just isn't getting properly installed...?  Or maybe one needs to be contributed...

tree -a | grep desktop doesn't get anything in that folder, so I don't think it is included there. The img folder mainly contains images which are used to display the GUI of the application, my guess is scid.gif is also used for rendering purposes in some part of the app itself, rather than to serve as the desktop icon.

The desktop file would not be in the image directory, probably somewhere else in the source tree.  But, like I said...maybe they need one contributed!

I'll look for it and maybe contribute.  But I'm living much further out on the bleeding edge than I thought I'd be with this OS.  This is basic stuff.  Feels like we're regressing here.

@alpha_ulrich: this suggestion almost works. I found an icon on the old machine and adding it to a desktop file (~/.local/share/applications) does cause the app to appear in the Show Apps grid.  From there, it can be pinned to the rid.dash, where it shows up with the icon.  However, there is no icon displayed on the Show Apps grid itself.

Unpinning it from the dash causes the icon to now appear in the Show Apps grid.
